# How to draw a gate diagram for F = w'x'y' + w'yz + wxz' + y'z' + wy' using only NOR gates, and w', x', y', z' inputs are not possible?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I optimized F(w,x,y,z) =  M(2,5,6,10,11,15) this and got F = w'x'y' + w'yz + wxz' + y'z' + wy'. I was asked to build the gate diagram of the equation using only NOR gates, and w', x', y', z' inputs are not possible. I have tried, but ended up using NOT gate several times.

Comment: You can use a NOR gate as an inverter, surely?

Answer (score 4):

NOR is a universal gate along with NAND. You can try now.

[image]